# laravel 5 How can I query

Tags: php, sql, laravel, pdo

PHP also made ​​my query in laravel can not.

this my PDO code.

```
$query2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM veriler WHERE masraf_kodu='$hesap_kodu' AND tarih BETWEEN '$tarih1' AND '$tarih2'", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

how can laravel 5 controller query ?

masraf_kodu  data table, hesap kodu plans database

Comment: Read Laravel documentation for this. Its very easy [https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart] .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Query Builder, try [`whereBetween()`](https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses):

```
$data = DB::table('veriler')
             ->where('masraf_kodu', $hesap_kodu)
             ->whereBetween('tarih', [$tarih1, $tarih2])
             ->get();
```